# Java HTTP proxy wont connect

Tags: java, http, proxy

How to connect properly using HTTP proxy in java? I can do it with sockProxyHost, but not with http.proxyHost.
If i do with socks, it will wait out for the proxy to connect and then it will create the web request, but if i do it with http it will just create the request and dont connect to the proxy.

```java
System.setProperty("http.proxySet", "true"); 
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "validproxyip"); 
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "validproxyport");
```

is my code. but it wont connect to the proxy. Please help!

Comment: "but it wont connect to the proxy", what do you mean? did you inspect the http text? like 407 code, or something else? when you in a company, they do not only have fire walls and http proxy, but also have NTLM protocol, try to figure out is the problem of NTLM verification。

Comment: Home computer and all. Will use public http proxies to do this.
but it wont connect, it will just create the request with the computers original IP.

Comment: http.proxySet is an urban myth. It has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

[Check out the proxy documentation at Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)

Either you have a typo, or you are using https and not http, or you access a "No-proxy" host. If you want to be sure, use the ProxySelector.

Comment: Do i need to call the proxy code above the request code or can i call it in a void like connectProxy()? Thats the only thing i can think about now.

Comment: How are you connecting to other computers? Using `URL` class? If so, then you first need to set the proxy and then when connecting, the `URL`will automatically use your proxy settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try set it in the vm args

> java -DproxyHost=proxy.mydomain.com -DproxyPort=3128 your.Main

Comment: This will change proxy several times during runtime so i cant do it. Also why is it DproxyHost?